# JMenu with checkbox and submenu

Tags: java, swing, jmenu

I need to create the `JMenu` which should have:

1. The `submenu` items
2. The `checkbox`.

Like this:

[image: JMenu with checkbox]

Is there any easy way to create it or I have to <s>learn the core first</s> merge the `JCheckBoxMenuItem` and `JMenu` classes?

**PS:** Yes, I know that I can try it myself and I'll create it after ~2 days of coding. I've just asked for the easy way or the turnkey solution.

Comment: What do you want to happen when you click the checkbox menu? Should you always be allowed to expand it, or only when it's checked?

Comment: It should always expand. But I need to add the `actionListener` to this `JMenu` to operate the `checkBox` status change.

Comment: You can associate an icon with any menu. The easiest way to do this might be to just use a regular MenuItem and set its icon to either a checked or unchecked checkbox whenever it is clicked. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html

Comment: Dirty hack, I've thought about that :)

Comment: I don't really think it's that dirty. Better than going the other way and trying to add all the submenu functionality to a JCheckBoxMenuItem!

Comment: It's dirty a little. Other ways a dirty a lot! Thanks. Please add your comment as an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can associate an icon with any menu. The easiest way to do this might be to just use a regular MenuItem and set its icon to either a checked or unchecked checkbox whenever it is clicked. You might put that logic in a subclass of JMenu and use that class.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html